# Check if input matches STEAM ID Format

Tags: javascript, pattern-matching

I understand how to match it but I don't know the criteria for example, Email matcher would use: `/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/` but I need to know what a steam id would use.

Demo Steam ID: STEAM_0:1:20206720

Could someone give me a criteria for STEAM IDs?

EDIT:
I'm using the regex expression provided by pimvdb, but it still replys that a steam id(STEAM_0:1:20206720) is incorrect.

My code is below:

```
function verifySteamID(){
    var elem = document.getElementById('item_name');
    var emailExp = /^STEAM_[0-5]:[01]:\d+$/;
    if(elem.value.match(emailExp)){
        document.getElementById("error").setAttribute("class", "hidden");
        return true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("error").setAttribute("class", "unhidden");
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
    }
```

Which is called by:

```
<input type="submit" value="Donate" id="donatebtn" onclick="return verifySteamID()" />
```

Comment: Google helped me: http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamID#Format

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamID#Format it might be something along the lines of:

```
/^STEAM_[0-5]:[01]:\d+$/
```

`^...$` is just so that the exact string must match.

`STEAM_` is the prefix.

After the prefix there should be one number ranging from 0 to 5.

Then a `:` followed by either a 0 or 1.

Then another `:` followed by the account number.

Comment: It still replys that my steam id is incorrect, I've edited my question to include the js code

Comment: @Harry: `/^STEAM_[0-5]:[01]:\d+$/.test("STEAM_0:1:20206720")` gives me `true`.

Comment: @Harry: Your demo ID works. What value are you using? Perhaps it's a slightly better idea to use `/^STEAM_[0-5]:[01]:\d+$/.test(str)`. This simply returns either `true` or `false`.

Comment: @pimvdb I've edited my script to your fiddle but I still get a incorrect statement, check my post for my script.

Comment: @Harry: What's `elem.value` if you alert it?

Comment: My god, you just reminded me that I had a hidden value with the same ID, Thank you.. it works flawlessly now

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var input = "STEAM_0:1:20206720"; 
var isValid = /^STEAM_\d:\d:\d+$/.test(input); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but the following RegEx expression works for me:
`^STEAM_[0-5]:[0-1]:[0-9]*$`

**How it works:**

- `^STEAM_` checks for the "STEAM_" string at the beginning of the SteamID.
- `[0-5]:` looks for an integer between 0 and 5 included, followed by ":".
- Same thing for `[0-1]:`.
- `[0-9]*$`checks that all the following characters are integers between 0 and 9 included.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to explain how it works?